# SQLAlchemy: get values of column where the only value for another column is X without using DISTINCT ON?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a table model:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Data(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    stock = Column(String)
    customer = Column(String)
```

I want to return the distinct values of `stock` for which the only value in `customer` is `"Alice"`. For example:

| stock | customer |
| --- | --- |
| A | Alice |
| A | Alice |
| A | Bob |
| B | Alice |
| C | Bob |

In this case, I want the result to be only `["B"]`.

This is fairly straightforward with Postgres:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('connection_string')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

result = session.query(Data.stock).distinct(Data.stock).filter(
    Data.customer == "Alice"
).group_by(Data.stock).having(
    ~Data.stock.in_(session.query(Data.stock).filter(Data.customer != "Alice"))
)
print([r for r in result])
```

This works, but makes use of Postgres' DISTINCT ON, and I want my query to be database-agnostic (MySQL, SQLite etc.). I'm not sure how to adapt it to be so. In fact, when running this with SQLite, I get the warning:

```
SADeprecationWarning: DISTINCT ON is currently supported only by the PostgreSQL dialect.  Use of DISTINCT ON for other backends is currently silently ignored, however this usage is deprecated, and will raise CompileError in a future release for all backends that do not support this syntax.
```

How can I perform this query in SQLAlchemy and be database-agnostic?

Comment: try using subqueries and aggregation. Whereas the first subquery counts the total number of customers for each stock and the second subquery counts the number of times "Alice" is the customer for each stock. Then by joining these two subqueries on the stock column, you can compare the total count to the count of "Alice". If these numbers are equal, it means that "Alice" is the only customer for that stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a subquery:

```py
subquery = session.query(Data.stock).filter(Data.customer != "Alice").distinct().subquery()
query = session.query(Data.stock).filter(Data.customer == "Alice").group_by(Data.stock).having(~Data.stock.in_(subquery))
print([result.stock for result in query])
```

Thanks to @Obaskly for pointing me toward subqueries.